# EGit could not detect where Git is installed warning is coming even we are not use Git in our project in Eclipse rich client platform

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, egit

We have desktop application which uses eclipse rich client platform(eclipse RCP) and when I run the application it always shows these Egit and home environment warnings even we are not using Git in our project.

I know one solution which requires to install git and configure it in eclipse- RCP get an option in windows-preference-Team- Git- confirmation and warnings from where we can deactivate these warnings.

But why we install Git if we are not using it and why to increase size of desktop application through installing git.

So, my question is how to deactivate these Egit warnings without having Git install?.

Comment: It sounds like you are including the egit plug-ins in your RCP - review what you are including in the RCP and remove them.

Comment: Which warning message is shown when where on what operating system? EGit is based on JGit and does not required the command line Git installed at all. Are you talking about [this](https://git.eclipse.org/c/egit/egit.git/commit/?id=7545e66c83f54777e06db05390854939e925fdce)? Does having the two following lines in your `plugin_customization.ini` help: `org.eclipse.egit.ui/show_home_drive_warning=false` and `org.eclipse.egit.ui/show_git_prefix_warning=false`?

Comment: @howlger Thanks, org.eclipse.egit.ui/show_home_drive_warning=false org.eclipse.egit.ui/show_git_prefix_warning=false added these two in plugin_customization.ini and now it was successfully deactivated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EGit is based on JGit and does not required the command line Git installed at all. I guess you talking about [this warning that is shown when Git's system-wide settings cannot be found](https://git.eclipse.org/c/egit/egit.git/commit/?id=7545e66c83f54777e06db05390854939e925fdce) (to warn about possible problems when using both EGit and the Git command line, as they should use the same and not separate system-wide settings).

If so, add the following two lines in your `plugin_customization.ini` to disable the warning:

```
org.eclipse.egit.ui/show_home_drive_warning=false
org.eclipse.egit.ui/show_git_prefix_warning=false
```